# how to stop generating different image sizes from parser

Tags: images

I am creating a parser that is parsing an XML file and uploading an image to media library. Everything works fine.

But after uploading, the different image as per Media Settings are also generated. For eg: Medium, Thumbnail etc.

I want to stop generating the duplicate image of different size only to those images ( images that are uploaded from parsing ). Is that possible?

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
$filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $uploadfile ), null );

$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => basename( $uploadfile ),
    'post_mime_type' => $filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $uploadfile ) ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
);

$attach_id   = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $uploadfile );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $uploadfile );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

return $attach_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't do this. As simple as that

Comment: Wrong. You can add/remove image sizes. Remove the image sizes during this parser, and they won't be recognized as image sizes in the system during this process.

Comment: yes. so how I can do this.. I was trying by doing `remove_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes' );` but did not worked